# How to seperate the string which contains ", " and " / " in different Scenerio

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

I want to call to a number which comes from JSON. But in one scenario "," is coming in this data and in another scenario "/" is coming. How can I give the condition to seperate that data?

Here is my code

```
if ([strNumbers containsString:@"/"]) {
        arrOfNumber = [strNumbers componentsSeparatedByString:@"/"];

}
else if([strNumbers containsString:@","])
{
arrOfNumber = [strNumbers componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
}
```

When it goes to `if` condition app gets crash.

Comment: What is arrOfNumber?

Comment: array of number is the array which i passed to tableview label.

Comment: for making call purpose

Comment: Hey would you show us declaration of strNumbers?

Comment: NSString *strNumbers = [_arrOfContactNum objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; when i remove if and else condition the for individual , and / this code works

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: Possibility: `strNumbers` when containing @"," may be interpreted as `NSNumber` and not `NSString`, which should give you "[NSNumber unrecongizedSelector:containsString:]" (or something like that), in which case your parsing is not complete. That's a long shot, but you really should give us your error message, either wise, that's just pure guess without really getting the real issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try with this.

```
NSString *string = @"cat,dog/home ,versity";
NSCharacterSet *charSet = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@",/"];
NSArray *array = [string componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:charSet];
NSLog(@"array:%@",array);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use it like this.

```
if ([strNumbers isKindOfClass:[NSString Class]])
{
     if ([strNumbers containsString:@"/"]) 
     {
        arrOfNumber = [strNumbers componentsSeparatedByString:@"/"];
     }
     else if([strNumbers containsString:@","])
     {
        arrOfNumber = [strNumbers componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
     }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

ContainsString method doesnot support to ios7. 
I replaced "/" by ",".
 strNumbers = [strNumbers stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"/" withString:@","];
Now it works properly